# How do I approach this equation?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integration, indefinite-integrals

This is the equation:

\begin{eqnarray*}
f\left(e\right) & = & -r\left(e\right)\left(1+\int_{E}\cos\left(s\left(e\right)-s\left(e'\right)\right)de'-\int_{I}\cos\left(s\left(e\right)-s\left(i\right)\right)di\right)
\end{eqnarray*}

All functions are one-to-one and range between $-1$ and $1$. The functions $r$ and $s$ evaluate to constants not to other functions. However, they are not linear but more like a hash. The subscripts on the integrals denote the domains.

**Edit**

I began by expanding the integrals to isolate terms. For example, what follows is an expansion of the *middle term* of the right-hand side.

\begin{eqnarray*} 
\int_{E}\cos\left(s\left(e\right)-s\left(e'\right)\right)de'=\cos\left(s\left(e\right)\right)\int_{E}\cos\left(s\left(e'\right)\right)de'-\sin\left(e\right)\int_{E}\sin\left(s\left(e'\right)\right)de' 
\end{eqnarray*}

How can I evaluate these integrals?

Comment: Where is the differential? What is the unknown? What do you call functions which evaluate to constants? Etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What does "functions evaluate to constants" mean? What are $E$ and $I$? How is this a functional integral if $r,s$ are functions but the *parameters being integrated* over, $e'$ and $i$, are presumably numbers? Perhaps you're doing a functional integral, and the quantity being integrated is the evaluation of varying functions at given arguments?

Comment: The differentials are $de'$ and $di$. The variables over which to integrate are $e'$ and $i$. By "functions which evaluate to constants", I meant a univariate function I guess. (Like the computer science idea of evaluating to a literal instead of another function.)

Comment: $f$ depends only on $e$. What are the relations b/w $f$ and $s$ besides of the equation you wrote?

Comment: @anon Yes, $e'$ and $i$ are numbers. I thought this was a functional integral because the argument to cosine is a function. Can I do anything if $s$ and $r$ don't have a closed form. Like I said they are hashes.

Comment: @Ilya $r$ and $s$ depend only on $e$. $f$ depends on $e,e'$ and $i$.

Comment: you can't evaluate those integrals since you don't know what function $s$ is. In the nutshell, it's not an equation: substitute there ANY functions $r$ and $s$ and you'll get some function $f$

Comment: It was always clear that $E,F$ were domains of integration. Can you  tell us what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @mac389 At present, $f$ depends on $e$, not on $e'$ nor on $i$.

Comment: @Did, how can that be true? Doesn't it depend on $i$? Look at the top line. The second line is only an expansion of the middle term of the top line.

Comment: @mac389 (I only looked at the top line since $f$ is defined on the top line...) The integral on $I$ does not depend on $i$ for the same reason that the integral on $E$ does not depend on $e'$. Both are functions on $e$ only. Do you have problems with one assertion and not the other?

Comment: @Did I am missing something. The second integral in the top line is over $di$

Comment: Precisely: $\int\limits_I\cos(s(e)-s(i))di=\int\limits_I\cos(s(e)-s(w))dw=\int\limits_I\cos(s(e)-s(\alpha))d\alpha=...$